# macOS - How do I force quit an app using the same machanism the system Force Quit menu uses from command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, monterey, force-quit

I'm on macOS Monterey and this is the system Force Quit menu:

[image]

I know how to quit or kill an app from command line, either using `osascript` or `kill / killall` - but they don't do the exact same thing the system Force Quit menu does.

Can I force quit an app using the same machanism the system Force Quit menu uses from command line?

Comment: How do you see Force Quit differ from `kill`?

Comment: @nohillside I'm not sure if there's a difference. I think macOS knows the processes an app is associated with and using the Force Quit menu cleanly `kill -9` them all. To do that without the FQ menu I'd have to find all those processes myself, and I might leave some process behind.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the workflow in which killing apps on the command line is happening. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `kill` is a lot more manageable once you know about [`pgrep -lafi`](https://linuxize.com/post/pgrep-command-in-linux/) and its close cousin, `pkill`.  They're not as clean as Force Quit, but get you most of the way.

Comment: @benwiggy I sometimes need to quit an app but the app doesn't respond to cmd-Q or osascript's `tell my.app to quit` well (it hangs), and I have to force quit it.

Comment: @JLPeyret Thanks for the pgrep tip! I think I could just use `pkill appname` instead.

Comment: Yes, if an app is unresponsive, then it won't respond to  quit events. However, if you have to do this regularly, then I'd look to fixing the cause of why the app is hanging.

Comment: You can also quit an irresponsive app from the Apple menu. Just press Shift so that "Force Quit..." becomes "Force Quit <app>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) / [pkill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) combo.

1. Tune your search with `pgrep` first.  I'll nuke Firefox here.

`pgrep -lafi firefox`

(truncating with `| head | cut -c-50`):

```
34536 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/fir
34539 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34540 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34541 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34544 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34549 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34550 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34551 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34557 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
34583 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plu
```

2. just switch to `pkill`, **keeping same arguments**:

(Kinda like doing `ls <complicated patter>` before running `rm <complicated pattern>`)

`pkill -lafi firefox`

(this was a different run which is why the PIDs differ)

```
kill -15 390
kill -15 509
kill -15 671
kill -15 25256
kill -15 25265
kill -15 25296
kill -15 25303
kill -15 25309
kill -15 26301
kill -15 26306
kill -15 26307
kill -15 26308
kill -15 34489
kill -15 41143
kill -15 41498
kill -15 50615
kill -15 97395
```

pkill takes extra stuff too: `pkill -9`

p.s. re. a comment: As to why someone's workflow would prefer command line over **Force Quit**?  Their business, init?  Many people are more productive on shells.  Doesn't have to be a malfunction either:  in my case, it might be an `npm run watch` server daemon that I want to launch to test, and then kill.  And that puppy **doesn't** show up on F Q.